# Segmentation violation wiringpi

Tags: c, wiringpi

I have a problem with the following code. I think it's a pointer issue but I don't know how to solve it.

I want to call the SIM7070_Start function from main. This function calls SIM7070_SendCommand and then the error appears.
It is related to the 'serial' variable of WiringPi?

please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

const int pwr = 4;
const int dtr = 25;

int SIM7070_PowerOn()
{
   printf("SIM7070_PowerOn\n");
   pinMode(pwr, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(pwr, HIGH);
   delay(2000);
   digitalWrite(pwr, LOW);
   delay(2000);

   pinMode(dtr, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(dtr, LOW);
   delay(1000);

}

int SIM7070_powerDown(void)
{
   printf("SIM7070_PowerDown\n");
   digitalWrite(pwr, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
   digitalWrite(pwr, LOW);
   delay(2000);

}

int SIM7070_SendCommand(int serial, char * command, char * expectedResponse)
{
   char data;
   data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

   printf("\nSEND COMMAND IS: %s\n", command);

   serialPrintf(serial, command);
   delay(200);

   while (serialDataAvail(serial)) {
       data = serialGetchar(serial);
       printf("%s", data);
   }

   if (strlen(expectedResponse) != 0) {
       if (strcmp(data, expectedResponse) <= 0) {
           printf("\nSIM7070_SendCommand - The expected response has been found\n");
           return 1;
       } else {
           printf("\nSIM7070_SendCommand - The expected response hasn't been found\n");
           return 0;
       }
   }
}

void SIM7070_Start(int serial)
{
   SIM7070_SendCommand(serial, "AT\r\n", "OK");
}

int main()
{
   int serial;
   char data;

   if (wiringPiSetup() < 0)
       return 1;
   if ((serial = serialOpen("/dev/ttyS0", 57600)) < 0)
       return 1;

   printf("Serial start ...\n");

   SIM7070_PowerOn();
   delay(2000);

   SIM7070_Start(serial);

   delay(5000);
   serialClose(serial);
   SIM7070_powerDown();

   return 0;
}
```

if main is:

```
int main()
{
   int serial;
   char data;

   if (wiringPiSetup() < 0)
       return 1;
   if ((serial = serialOpen("/dev/ttyS0", 57600)) < 0)
       return 1;

   printf("Serial start ...\n");

   SIM7070_PowerOn();
   delay(2000);

   SIM7070_SendCommand(serial, "AT\r\n", "OK");

   delay(5000);
   serialClose(serial);
   SIM7070_powerDown();

   return 0;
}
```

it works.

Comment: `*data = serialGetchar(serial);` but `char *data` has not been assigned a value.

Comment: Hello Paul,I do not understand.
What should I do?

Comment: `data` must point to valid memory in function `SIM7070_SendCommand`

Comment: why `char *data` anyway and not `char data`?

Comment: I want to compare data with expectedResponse. I edit the post to show it.

Comment: Sorry. I am a beginner

Comment: `data = serialGetchar(serial);` gets a single character, so you cannot `printf ("%s", data);` which prints a string. Turn warnings of your compiler on to get feedback.

Comment: Not being familiar with `wiringpi` I'd like just a bit more explanation before you jump into: `SIM7070_Start`.  Just a brief description of what you're doing and on what platform.  It may not be 100% necessary, but it would make me feel less lost.

Comment: Also, at the bottom of your question I'd like to see a detailed description of error / symptoms.  I know you name the type of error in the question's title, but in general every error type question should have a detailed error description in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also my comments. You may want a loop like:

```
char data[256], *pData= data;
while(serialDataAvail(serial)){ 
   *pData++ = serialGetchar(serial);     
}
*pData= '\0';
printf ("%s", data);
```

This uses an array of chars to place the data received into. Pointer variable `pData` then points to this buffer and increments with each character received. At the end it terminates the (string) buffer with a terminating null character.

Comment: you might want to add a check to avoid reading more than 255 characters

Comment: e.g. `int i = 0; for (; i < 255 && serialDataAvail(serial); i++) { data[i] = serialGetchar(serial); } data[i] = 0;`